# Post to MySQL DB Failed

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I'm using a script which posts to a db for admin approval. For some reason when i try and take out a few of the fields (`photoname`, `emailid`) in the PHP section post seems to fail when I click submit. I've tried deleting the fields from the db also but it still gives me the same error. Specifically outputs this  `$errmsg = "Adding Testimonial failed."`;

```
<form name="addform" action="submit.php" id="myform2"     enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onSubmit="javascript:return validatefrm();">
```

**FORM**

```
                <label>Your Name</label>
                <input class="input" type="text" name="client_id" size=50 maxlength="20">

            <label>Rating</label>
                    <select name="rating">
                        <option value="">Select 
                        <option value="5">5 Excellent
                        <option value="1">1 Poor
                    </select>

            <label>Project Title</label>
                    <input name="proj_desc" type="text" value="" size="50">

            <div class="item">
                                    <span class="label">Date *</span>
                                    <div class="option">
                                        <div class="select_wrapper selects">
                                                <select name="day" class="select">
                                                <option value="" selected="">Day</option>
                                                <?php
                                                for ($i=1; $i <= 31; $i++) { 
                                                    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'. $i .'</option>';

                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="select_wrapper selectm">
                                            <select name="month" class="select">
                                                <option value="" selected="">Month</option>
                                                <option value="01">Jan</option>
                                                <option value="02">Feb</option>
                                                <option value="03">Mar</option>
                                                <option value="04">Apr</option>
                                                <option value="05">May</option>
                                                <option value="06">Jun</option>
                                                <option value="07">Jul</option>
                                                <option value="08">Aug</option>
                                                <option value="09">Sep</option>
                                                <option value="10">Oct</option>
                                                <option value="11">Nov</option>
                                                <option value="12">Dec</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="select_wrapper selectm">
                                                <select name="year" class="select">
                                                    <option value="" selected="">Year</option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
                                                    $year = date('Y');
                                                    for ($i= $year; $i >= 1990; $i--) { 
                                                        echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'. $i .'</option>';

                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>


            <label>Comments</label>
                <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="feedback"></textarea>

            <br>
                <input type="submit" class="submitbutton" name="Add" value="Send Feedback">

            </form>
```

PHP & JS Validate

```
            <?php
                require_once('include/function.php');

                // Storing the Testimonial Details in Variables
                $addtestmonial  =   isset($_POST['Add'])? $_POST['Add']:'';
                if ( $addtestmonial ) {

                        $client_id      = addslashes( htmlspecialchars( $_POST['client_id'] ) );
                        $photoname      = addslashes( htmlspecialchars( $_POST['photoname'] ) );
                        $proj_date      = $_POST['year']."-".$_POST['month']."-".$_POST['day'];
                        $feedback       = addslashes( htmlspecialchars( $_POST['feedback'] ) );
                        $emailid        = addslashes( htmlspecialchars( $_POST['emailid'] ) );
                        $proj_desc      = addslashes( htmlspecialchars( $_POST['proj_desc'] ) );
                        $rating         = isset($_POST['rating'])? $_POST['rating']:'';
                        $companyname    = addslashes( htmlspecialchars( $_POST['companyname'] ) );

                        if ( $_FILES['photo']['name'] ) {

                            $photofile = $base_dir . date(His).basename( $_FILES['photo']['name'] );
                            if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $photofile ) ) {
                                $photoname = date(His).$_FILES['photo']['name'];
                            }
                        }

                        //Query for inserting the Testimonial Values in the Database
                        $sql    = "INSERT INTO review VALUES('','$client_id','$rating','$proj_date','$proj_desc','$photoname','$companyname','$feedback',0,'$emailid')";
                        if ( $client_id && $emailid && $rating && $proj_date && $proj_desc && $feedback )
                            $rset = mysql_query( $sql );

                        // Code for sending mail when a new testimonial has been Added
                        if ( $rset && mysql_affected_rows()>0 ) {
                            $to         = $useremail;                    
                            $subject    = 'New Testimonial Added';
                            $message    = "Testimonial Details". "\r\n" ;
                            $message    .='Client Name :'.stripslashes( $client_id ). "\r\n" ;
                            $message    .='Testimonial :' .stripslashes( $feedback ). "\r\n" ;
                            $headers    = 'From:' .$to . "\r\n" ;

                            @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
                            $successmsg  =  "Testimonial has been added Successfully.";
                        }else if ( mysql_errno() == 1062 ) {
                            $errmsg = "Duplicate data.";
                        }else {
                            $errmsg = "Adding Testimonial failed.";
                        }

                }

                ?>

                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function validatefrm() 
                    {
                        var frm = document.addform;
                        if ( frm.client_id.value === "" ) {
                            alert("Enter Client ID/Name");
                            frm.client_id.focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                        else if( frm.emailid.value === "" )
                        {
                            alert("Enter Email-ID");
                            frm.emailid.focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                        else if ( frm.day.value === "" ) {
                            alert("Select Day");
                            frm.day.focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                        else if ( frm.month.value === "" ) {
                            alert("Select Month");
                            frm.month.focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                        else if ( frm.year.value === "" ) {
                            alert("Select Year");
                            frm.year.focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                        else if ( frm.proj_desc.value === "" ) {
                            alert("Enter Title");
                            frm.proj_desc.focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                        else if( frm.rating.value === "" ) {
                            alert("Select Ratings");
                            frm.rating.focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                        else if( frm.feedback.value === "" ) {
                            alert("Enter Testimonial");
                            frm.feedback.focus();
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }

                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                        jQuery('.select_wrapper').each(function () {
                            jQuery(this).prepend('<span>' + jQuery(this).find('.select option:selected').text() + '</span>');
                        });
                        jQuery('.select').on('change', function () {
                            jQuery(this).prev('span').replaceWith('<span>' + jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text() + '</span>');
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: You say that it gives you an error, but you don't tell us what the error is.

Comment: Don't use JavaScript checks only, users will be able to remove them / disable them. Add checks in your PHP checks as well.

Comment: Just says failed to write  e.g. when i submit the form